# How to check a property from a component - Jasmine & Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

In a test I am writing, I want to check the value of a property from the component.

Component:

```
addMode:boolean;
addItem = () => {
  this.addMode = true;
}
```

After I click on the 'addItem' button, 'addMode' should be change to true and I want to check/test this. Test file:

```
it('Should check if #addItem button no longer exists', () => {
     component.addItem();    //  click on the button
     expect(component.addMode).toBeTruthy();
});
```

but if I check the value of `component.addMode`, I get `undefined`. 
What is the correct way to check the value of that variable before and after I click the button? Thanks

Comment: try running `fixture.detectChanges()` before the expect statement

Comment: @BorisLobanov - Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. The variable is still undefined. If I log `component` in the console (from the tests file), `addMode` doesn't appear as a property on it.

Comment: could you post more code from the component and the test setup? you can also try to set it up in stackblitz, I'll try to help

Comment: @BorisLobanov - I cannot set it up in stackblitz, but I can show you the code here: http://sorincozma.co.uk/test/jasmine/
Thanks!

Comment: well, that really limits my ability to help. it looks like addMode doesn't get initialized anywhere. there's probably something wrong either with the test or the component itself

Comment: I guess you can still do something like:
    `component.addMode = false;`
    `component.addItem();`
    `expect(component.addMode).toBe(true);`

Comment: I will do it like this, many thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166235/discussion-between-decebal-and-boris-lobanov).

Answer (score 0):

voila !

```
it('Should check if #addItem button no longer exists', () => {
         component.addItem();    //  click on the button
         fixture.detectChanges()
         expect(component.addMode).toBeTruthy();
    });
```